# Object Returns Two Dict How Do I Look Only At One Dict

Tags: xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Sorry, I feel like this may be a total noob question, however the things I have tried do not seem to be working.

I have an XML file with a couple of the following sections:

```
    <ns:ServiceTechnicianParty>
      <ns:SpecifiedPerson>
        <ns:ID>TECH005</ns:ID>
        <ns:GivenName>Technician 005</ns:GivenName>
        <ns:FamilyName>Technician 005</ns:FamilyName>
      </ns:SpecifiedPerson>
    </ns:ServiceTechnicianParty>
```

My to read this looks like this:

```
for specified_person in soup.find_all('ns:servicetechnicianparty'):
    person = {child.name: child.text for child in specified_person.findChildren()}
    print person
```

Which returns the following:

```
 {'ns:givenname': u'Technician 001', 'ns:specifiedperson': u'\nTECH001\nTechnician 001\nTechnician 001\n', 'ns:familyname': u'Technician 001', 'ns:id': u'TECH001'}
 {'ns:givenname': u'Technician 005', 'ns:specifiedperson': u'\nTECH005\nTechnician 005\nTechnician 005\n', 'ns:familyname': u'Technician 005', 'ns:id': u'TECH005'}
```

So what I would like to know is how do I get 1 `dict` at a time as I am trying to compare what is in the XML to what is being displayed in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my code so that I got a list of dictionaries, rather than two dictionaries separately. Thank you very much to Benjamin for sparking my mind with this.

```
peoples = []
for specified_person in soup.find_all('ns:servicetechnicianparty'):
    person = {child.name: child.text for child in specified_person.findChildren()}
    for people in person:
        peoples.append(person)
print peoples[0]
```

Thank you once again to Benjamin Drury for inspiring this idea.

Answer (score 1):

So it's returning a list of dicts? If that is the case, you should be able to access just one at a time by specifying one. Try `print person[0]` just to check what it is actually doing here.

Comment: It is not returning a list of dicts, it is returning two dicts, however you gave me an idea. To make it a list of dicts. I made `person = [{}]' now it returns two lists with a dictionary inside of them.